# How To Grab Domain & Sanitize And Validate Domain?

Tags: validation, filter, proxy, dns

How can I make sure User inputted a valid domain on my webform when I prompt him for his domain name ?

1. My attempt which failed to validate domain:
   [php]

   if (filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN)) {
     echo("$domain is a valid Domain");
   } else {
     echo("$domain is not a valid domain");
   }
   ?> 
   [/php]

Code must be foolproof.

2. Say, proxied link looks like this:
   http://www.proxy.com/?proxied_page=stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Now, how to grab the domain from a proxied paage url and validate the domain ?

3. If you were visiting this page:
   http://www.proxy.com/?proxied_page=stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Will you get counted as the proxy's visitor or the proxied domain's visitor ?
In this example, are you proxy.com's visitor or stackoverflow.com's according to technical debate aswell your international law or your country's law ?

Comment: You first need to define "valid" in "valid domain". Syntaxically valid? And if so you need to separate the definition of "domain name" from "host name" in the DNS specifications, so it depends where your "domain" is used. Or do you also need to check if it exists? If it resolves? Also in all request for help, when you say "My attempt which failed" you need to specify how it failed, what you expected instead as a result, etc. Points 2 and 3 in your posts are basically impossible to answer without more context.

Comment: @demonplus,

1. What I meant was, we have the FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL but FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN does not exist. And so, what is the workaround ?

2. In this url example:
http://www.proxy.com/?proxied_page=stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

proxy.com is the domain of the web proxy. And, stackoverflow.com is the domain of the proxied page or destination domain. How to grab the domain of the proxied page (destination domain) from such urls. Such urls meaning urls that contain both the proxy's domain and the proxied page's domain (destination domain).

Comment: @demonplus,

3. If you visit http://google.com then you are counted as the visitor of google.com. But, if you visit google.com via a web proxy then are you counted as the proxy's visitor or google's visitor ? So, if you were visiting google via proxy through this url:
http://www.proxy.com/?proxied_page=google.com/contactus.php
then are you technically counted as the proxy's visitor (in this case proxy.com's visitor) or are you counted as google.com's visitor ? Note that, you, the visitor, is actually on the proxy's domain "proxy.com" and not on google.com. Bear this in  mind.

Comment: @patrick Mevzek,

I am providing visitors a webform to fill in to submit their website url. I need the input field to check whether the url is valid or not and then grab the domain name from the url. So, if the user inputs:
http://www.proxy.com/?proxied_page=stackoverflow.com/questions/ask then the domain validator should check if it's a valid domain or not. If not then give error.